# Pig: how to retrieve difference between two consecutive tuples. (int type)

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Suppose my Data is as follows:
(XXX,{(1),(2),(3)})

I will need the difference between tuples inside given bag. (there can be n number of tuples.)

Output i am expecting:
(XXX,2)

Is it possible without using UDF?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "difference"? I don't understand how you get 2 from the numbers 1, 2, and 3. Keep in mind also that bags are unordered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to flatten bag and then apply filter on the flatten dataset to select appropiate